# storing cache of pages at different location instead of default

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

i want to implement the concept of caching on my asp.net web application. it not a MVC application. i have learned how to do caching of pages (aspx)

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="none" Location="ServerAndClient" %>
```

it is catching the page. i want to store the cache in a folder at some different location instead of default. i dont know hoe to do that. and for the other page the folder will be different. is there some way to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: The cached data is in memory, not on disk (wouldn't make much sense to have it on disk).

Comment: by memory u mean ram? even if ram so can i define some way to store the cached data in some hierarchy? :)

Comment: Yes, I mean RAM. And what would such a change give you? I don't understand what you gain by doing so.

Comment: what i am thinking is that i am storing the cache of all pages of mywebsite on server in one folder (default). if i will keep them in hierarchy the server will find the cache of a page more fastly.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you use the [OutputCache] attribute, content is cached in three locations: the web server, any proxy servers, and the web browser. You can control exactly where content is cached by modifying the Location property of the [OutputCache] attribute.

You can set the Location property to any one of the following values:

· Any

· Client

· Downstream

· Server

· None

· ServerAndClient

Comment: see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs for cache section in asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4 allows you to create Custom Output Cache Provider

I understand you just want to configure you current code so the cache can store in a particular folder but the below article gives you example showing you can have a cahcheLocation set in your config file

This this example shows you how to store in Physical Disk File http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19835/Creating-a-Custom-Output-Cache-Provider-in-ASPNET-4.htm